# JavaScript sometimes does not work with IE 7,8,9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this code that changes the url every time a user clicks a button in the page.
That works great in safari,chrome,firefox but not in IE 7,8,9.
What could be the problem ?

```
function setNewNavigationUrls(){
    var musicParameter;
    if (isMusicOn) {
        musicParameter='1';
    }else{
        musicParameter='0';
    }

    $("a[href='/']").attr('href', '/?music='+musicParameter);
    $("a[href='/collection-glamour-feeling']").attr('href', '/collection-glamour-feeling?music='+musicParameter);
    $("a[href='/collection-poetic-moments']").attr('href','/collection-poetic-moments?music='+musicParameter);
    $("a[href='/about.html']").attr('href','/about.html?music='+musicParameter);
    $("a[href='/contact.html']").attr('href', '/contact.html?music='+musicParameter);
}
```

Thanks
Shani

Comment: what are the errors you are getting in IE?

Comment: Is `isMusicOn` defined elsewhere in your JavaScript?

Comment: Yes and again, everything is fine in other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should be using ".prop()" instead of ".attr()" to set the "href" of your `<a>` elements.

```
$("a[href='/']").prop('href', '/?music='+musicParameter);
// ... etc. ...
```

With jQuery 1.6, the semantics of "attr()" changed considerably. The "href" attribute becomes a **property** of the DOM node for the element, and therefore it should be set as a property. The "attr()" method now concerns itself with attributes (via "setAttribute()" and "getAttribute()"). Boolean properties like "checked" and "disabled" are treated in a backwards-compatible fashion following jQuery 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and replace: `if (isMusicOn)` to `if (typeof isMusicOn !== "undefined")` to be sure the statement gets evaluated correctly.

Comment: I've never experienced that sort of problem with IE.

Comment: @Pointy, it can happen in any browser. Not just IE.

Comment: Well if it's a completely undeclared variable, then IE might trigger an error, but other browsers not in "strict" mode will treat "undefined" as a falsy value.

Comment: @Pointy, not always. In more then one occasion, the browser threw an error that the variable did not exist. By using `typeof` in the condition, this problem never occur.

Comment: Well that may be the case. The OP here has, sadly (and sadly typically), not told us the  actual errors (if any).

Comment: Hi' sorry but i get no Errors in the console. the links works but they are not changed.

Comment: How do you call the function?